# openxlsx: Where is the data located in the workbook object

Tags: r, openxls

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "iris")
writeData(wb, "iris", iris)
```

Where can I find the data/tab data for `iris` in `wb`?

EDIT:

I would like to see the data in a R session and export it back as a R object to see what it contains. Reason is, I have a function (that I cant change) that returns a `workbook` object with data and I would like to explore the data in R additionally before saving it.

Comment: You have a typo, try: `wb <- createWorkbook()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`readWorkbook()`](https://ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/reference/readWorkbook.html) function reads Workbook objects as data frames.

```
openxlsx::readWorkbook(wb)

#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. but have you tried `openxlsx::openXL(wb)` ?

Comment: Not really what I am looking for, but thanks for mentioning that function, was not aware of it.